# Website missing images/text when viewed in Blackberry Devices

Tags: html, blackberry, mobile

So I'm making a mobile-optimized website and everything looks great on iphone, android, etc.

However, I looked at the site in BlackBerry (the newest version) and you can only see one image and one large background image.  About 90% of the website isn't visible.

The HTML and CSS is valid.  Are there any known issues I should design around when working with BlackBerry devices?

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What BBOS are you using? You say latest - 7?

5 is riddled with problems, 6 isnt much better.

What are the size of the images? BBOS Web browser will by default truincate them if they are too large (check it browser settings to change limit)

However im guessing if your making a mobile site your going to what it to adhere to the devices default settings...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I'm using the BB Torch simulator- which I believe is 7.  If it helps, I can provide the link to the development site.  The width of the site is all smaller than 320px.

Comment: If its a torch 9800, then is BBOS6. I meant the size in kb of the images. Not the size :)

Comment: Oh ok, haha.  There are about six images, all in the 4-10k range.  Strangely, the two images that show are some of the larger (in KB) images.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of RIM and its rubbish mobile browsers!

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out the problem:

I was using a span to hide some things by giving them a:

position: relative;
left: 9999px;

When we removed this, it started working fine.